# When user inputs "-" it does not show up in input box in Chrome, but works in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, inputbox

I have no problem getting this to work in Firefox. The program is that Chrome hides the text below the bottom of the input box. I think Chrome is only using the body tag's font and height and ignoring class completely as a stupid thing with stupid values that it thinks is not valid because it results in a super thin input box, which is by design. The user is only suppose to put in " _ " to "underline" the letter.

NOTE: Flex boxes do not work because Flex box is all about the content moving to fit the screen. I am trying to do something more akin to a Word Find where the user would simply put a "=" in the in put box, to indicate that they are underlining the letter. I need the input boxes and the letters to line up both Vertically and Horizontally.

UPDATE:
Flex box will wrap to the next line after you've closed your screen enough. I do not want a code that thinks for me. I know where I want things. Besides, Flex boxes do not make INPUT boxes allow input that shows up! Flex boxes do NOT have a thing to do with input boxes. The problem is that Chrome needs a HACK to force its God Code to stop playing God on my page. This is why I think I will just throw out Chrome and just use Firefox. At least Firefox actually ALLOWS MY CSS instead of ignoring it because IT thinks that IT knows best!

Things I have tried:

1. Changing Font size both increasing and decreasing the size.
2. Commenting out/not commenting out height, vertical-align, line-height values. 
   Thanks!

EDIT: The HTML and Updated CSS, and gave the JS too.

```
<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td class="grey"> Q </td>
<td class="grey"> A </td>
<td class="grey"> F </td>
<td class="grey"> O </td>
<td class="grey"> U </td>
<td class="grey"> R </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> &nbsp; </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c1" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c2" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c3" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c4" size="1"> </td>
<td><input class="zthin" type="text" name="c5" size="1"> </td>
</tr>
```

CSS Updated:

```
BODY {
background-color: #000000;
background-image:       url(/w5jyz84kw0dle38f19s0xceydkoyjs/velvela/gaming/2/word/xw/xwcss/ngc3.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: top left;
border: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

input.zthin { 
background-color: #c1c1c1;
border: 2px solid #0000ff;
font-size: 10pt;
height: 10pt;
line-height: 10pt;
padding:0px;
width:20px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function jyzcrossWord(){
if (document.form.c1.value=="-"
&& document.form.c2.value=="-"
&& document.form.c3.value=="-"
&& document.form.c4.value=="-"
&& document.form.c5.value=="-"
)
  alert("Congratulations! All is correct!")

else {alert("Not correct. Please check your answers.")}
}
</script>
```

Lastly, when I put '-' into the input box, I do not see it at all. If put 'm' I only see the upper half of the 'm'. In Firefox, it shows up properly. Also, class grey does not matter, as that part of the css was not the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the HTML you are using as well?  You haven't given anyone enough to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue now.

Comment: This is a CSS issue, not a JavaScript issue so I changed your tags.  I ran through the list of things I knew and I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for trying! Sorry for using html 4.01, but I was never able to make anything resembling a crossword game in CSS 3 and HTML 5, as the div tags refused to understand what I wanted. No one in their right mind, would use that to make games. They use flash and flash alternatives - things I am not capable of doing. lol

Comment: If I were making that game, I'd be trying HTML5 and the new(ish) css flex-box stuff.

Comment: I will need to learn how to use that. I apparently, suck as div tags outside of normal HTML pages. I was able to make a website that is not games, using html 5 and css 3, but that was a text based page. I have not tried the newish Flex box, but will take a look at that for that game. Thanks!